# The target "" of this Internet Shortcut is not valid

Tags: windows-installer, advanced-installer, shortcut-file

Our project has been renamed and so I'm updating the shortcuts in my installer using Advanced Installer (although the problem isn't limit to this platform, see the answer).  The new shortcuts won't work from the `Desktop` or `Start Menu` but will work from `Application Shortcut Folder`.  I can move a single shortcut between these locations and the same applies.

The symptoms:

- The shortcut displays a generate globe (ie: internet) icon.
- The following error message is displayed when trying to launch the shortcut

> The target "" of this Internet Shortcut is not valid. Go to the Internet Shortcut property sheet and make sure the target is correct.

**Edit**

It turns out that the name of the shortcut was the issue. Not entirely sure why; at first I thought it was a character length limitation.  I have to check with my employer before posting the name of the shortcut, but even renaming from the destkop causes this to occur, although if I substitute the last character for 2 more everything is fine.  Very strange!

**Edit 2**

It seems to be limited to my dev machine.  The shortcut doesn't appear to have issues on any others that I've tested.  Something I've done in development has messed it up and I would be very curious to know what that could be.

Comment: that is strange. usually the target of the shortcut is the problem. Can you mail me with more details on bogdan at advancedinstaller dot com?

Comment: Will do, although I can't reproduce it on my machine at home; both Windows 7 x64.

Comment: Actually, it seems that if I create the shortcut through the Windows wizard (doesn't allow me to specify the icon until after it's created) it works fine on both machines.  Will have to try running the installer on my home system later on.

Answer (score 0):

This shortcut has any space in the target file path? If so, remove it or wrap in quotes, that worked for me.

Comment: No, it was only issue on the one machine (the shortcut is created by an MSI during installation).